# Bind WPF combobox itemssource to property in another .cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a combobox to a property that I've got defined in another file.

The Combobox, in `OptionsWindow.xaml`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="InputDevicesComboBox"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Text="Please Select Input Device"
          ItemsSource="{Binding InputDeviceNames, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type SIPBandVoIPClient:MainWindow}}}"/>
```

The Property, in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
private List<string> _inputDeviceNames;
public List<string> InputDeviceNames
{
     get => _inputDeviceNames;
     private set
     {
          _inputDeviceNames = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("InputDeviceNames");
     }
}
```

The error, when opening the OptionsWindow:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='SIPBandVoIPClient.MainWindow', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=InputDeviceNames; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='InputDevicesComboBox'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')`

I recognize there are quite a few questions on this, but I don't really understand WPF bindings all that well and can't seem to get them to work...

I created this binding using the inbuilt binding creation in Visual Studio, so I figured it would work. After some searching, I think the issue is either that the property is in a different file, or it is not part of the visual tree (?).

I do have a binding with a property defined in MainWindow.xaml.cs, and bound in MainWindow.xaml that is working perfectly, hence my thinking it's due to being in a different file.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does `SIPBandVoIPClient` match your `namespace`?

Comment: @Sach MainWindow.xaml.cs is in the `SIPBandVoIPClient` namespace, yes. OptionsWindow.xaml.cs is in the `SIPBandVoIPClient.Windows` namespace. Visual studio appears to have generated this code, which looks like it's including the correct namespace: ```xmlns:SIPBandVoIPClient="clr-namespace:SIPBandVoIPClient"
        xmlns:Classes="clr-namespace:SIPBandVoIPClient.Classes" x:Class="SIPBandVoIPClient.Windows.OptionsWindow"```

Comment: OK I think as the posted answer suggest you should adopt a ViewModel approach. After all that is one of the main benefits of WPF so you're not tied to the window's code behind.

Comment: I did manage to get it working from the code by doing: ```var main = App.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;

            InputDevicesComboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding() {Source = main.InputDeviceNames});```, but now Dmitry has updated his answer, I think I'll try that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an view model object to exchange data between this two windows, and pass it to the DataContext of both windows instancies. Then you don't need any relative source in binding attribute, but just in Path set the name of property, containing your List.
Or better look at MVVM design pattern 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/13/understanding-the-basics-of-mvvm-design-pattern/

Create a View Model class mainViewModel.cs:

```
class MainViewModel {
    List<string> InputDeviceNames { get; private set; }
    public MainViewModel() {
        InputDeviceNames = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Then use it in your MainWindow.xaml.cs class:

```
private MainViewModel _viewModel;
public MainWindow() {
    _viewModel = new MainViewModel();
    DataContext = _viewModel;
    // anywhere in code you can use your _viewModel to exchange data
}
public OpenOptionsWindowCode() {
    var options = new OptionsWindow();
    options.DataContext = _viewModel;
    options.Show();
}
```

In your OptionsWindow.xaml :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="InputDevicesComboBox"
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
      Text="Please Select Input Device"
      ItemsSource="{Binding InputDeviceNames}"/>
```

If you use InputDeviceNames in binding in MainWindow.xaml be sure to notify the view on items changes. Then use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`.
And if you will extend your view model to hold other values implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on MainViewModel class.

MVVM is a powerful pattern for UI development, so after a little efforts on lerning it you acheve better results in less efforts.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks. Is it trivial to rework a small section of the code to support this, or does it require a large redesign? I'm working on a relatively large codebase so not sure how much I can alter easily.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Wow, this is way easier than I thought to implement! Thanks. Should `_model = new MainViewModel()` be `_viewModel`?